# How to sort through a list of strings and a list of numbers which are related, in python?

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I am creating a Student Grading program: it starts in input mode and asks for name, age, science grade, maths grade, and English grade.
Then there are multiple possible actions: add students, add school-classes, print every added student, and - print lowest-to-highest results in the different subjects. This last action is the one I am having problems with.

What I'm failing in is when the user inputs ‘4’ in the main menu, then user is asked if he/she wants to display the students maths, physics, or English results. When the user specifies what they want to display, something like the following will be produced:

```
Jill: 3
Marvin: 4
Jack: 6
Raf: 80
```

I know how to sort through the numbers with the sort() function but how do I make ‘jill’ go in the same place as ‘3’ on a list.

This is so I can do something like this:

```
for p in range(len(allStudents)):
    print(allStudents[p].printName(), ":" ,  mathsAll[p] , "/100")
```

I know that I could use a dictionary for this but then let’s say I input 2 users called “Jill”, then it will overwrite the first one.

full code can be found from: http://pastebin.com/R2uGAQVg
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Definitely need you to provide sample input and output.

Comment: I am unable to make any guesses about the data structure you're using, but I suspect that it's suboptimal. Tell us what you're working with and maybe we can suggest a better structure that'll make these tasks easier.

Comment: I'll make the program simpler. Just pretend there is a menu that can only recieve 2 inputs, if the user inputs 1, then user will be prompted to input : There science grade, their maths grade and their english grade and the name of the student. If the user inputs 4 then it will prompt the user to input either 1) maths 2) science 3) english. If the user inputs 1, then it will display all the students all the students maths results from lowest to highest. I can't just create a dict because if I input the same name twice, then it will overwrite. So how do you create a dict that doesn't overwrite.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pair the name with the value. If you don't want to use a dictionary for some reason, then use tuples.

```
data = [('Jill', 3), ('Marvin', 4), ('Jack', 6), ('Raf', 80)]

for datum in data:
    name, score = data
    # do whatever you like....
```

Or use a list of dictionaries

```
data = [{'name': 'Jill', 'score': '3'}, ... ]

for d in data:
    print(d['name'] + ": " + d['score'])
```

Or use `namedtuple`s.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Student = namedtuple('Student', ['name', 'score'])

data = [Student(name="Jill", score=3), ... ]

for student in data:
    print(data.name + ": " + data.score)
    # or print("{student.name}: {student.score}".format(student=student))
```

Or any of a number of other *better* ways to handle your data than two unrelated lists!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply!, the reason why I can't use dictionaries is because I the user is the one that types in the students name so if they type in the same name then it will overrite. What is the the difference between a tuple and a dictionary and does it overrite if a key is specified twice like dictionaries do?

Comment: If the students' first names can't serve as unique identifiers, I'd recommend using their student ID as a key, or maybe their first initial and last name (e.g. `jdoe`).

Comment: @mre12345 you need to think more specifically. Dictionaries don't overwrite if they have more than one *name*, they overwrite with duplicate *keys*. So you couldn't use anything non-unique for the key, but you could still store the data in a dictionary. See my examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your students in a class:

```
class Student:
   def __init__(self, name, math_grade):
       self.name = name
       self.math_grade = math_grade
```

then if you have a list of students `student_list`, you can sort the list by attribute:

```
student_list = [Student("Steve", 3), Student("Paul", 4), Student("Jack, 5")]
student_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.math_grade, reverse=True)
print(student_list)
```

Then if the students have more attributes (age, name, science grade, english grade, etc), is easy to sort them by changing the lambda.

If your application will hold information about students between runs, you should consider other kind of containers like an embedded database (such as SQL light).